# Is there any way to turn off touch on a Wacom tablet, without turning off the side buttons?

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet

I've got a Wacom Bamboo tablet (CTH-461) that I've got almost completely set up the way I want it.  For some reason, though, when I turn off the touch pad functionality for it, the buttons on the pad go with it.  Is there any way to bypass this?